# Tomcat startup script permission on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, tomcat, scripting

I'm struggling with a Mac OS X 10.5.8 that I've started using recently for development. I successfully installed tomcat and create launchd.conf for my environment variables.

I believe it works fine. Coz I can build a project with Netbeans using maven and cargo plugins successfully so i found [online](http://neilang.com/entries/how-to-install-tomcat-on-mac-os-x/) a script for start and stop the tomcat

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
 start)
  sh /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/startup.sh
 ;; 
 stop)
  sh /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/shutdown.sh
 ;;
 restart)
  sh /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/shutdown.sh
  sh /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/startup.sh
 ;;
 *)
 echo "Usage :start|stop|restart"
 ;;
 esac
 exit 0
```

That script was created in nano in sudo sh
but when i want to run it. is spit out this

> sh: /usr/bin/tomcat: Permission denied

I've added `chmod 755 *.sh and *.bat inside /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin`

Still access denied so what do I go around that? I have the admin privileges on the machine.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where did you install the tomcat script to? I'd recommend you install it to `/usr/bin`.  Once installed, make sure the permissions are correct (i.e. `chmod 755 /usr/bin/tomcat`). You can then confirm with `ls -l /usr/bin/tomcat`.

If you still get errors once the permissions on `/usr/bin/tomcat` are correct, then you can add the following two lines following the `#!/bin/bash` line.

```
set -x
set -v
```

With the above lines, bash will output additional information that will allow you to tell what's being executed and where the error is happening.

Comment: ok thanks very much for the tips.it does start and stop the server but then when i execute the tomcat stop it throwing an exception but it's stoping the server though

Comment: here are my environment variables inside /etc/launchd.conf 
setenv JAVA_VERSION 1.6
setenv JAVA_HOME /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/
setenv JRE_HOME /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/
setenv CATALINA_BASE /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20
setenv CATALINA_HOME /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20
setenv CATALINA_TMPDIR /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/temp

Comment: and here are the error
EVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:372)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:186)

Comment: at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:186)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:422)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:337)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)

Comment: Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/
touch: /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
/Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/catalina.sh: line 310: /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied

Comment: solve it. but it seems that netbeans nor eclispe can't publish to it.on netbeans i have this : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Library/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/work/Catalina/localhost/host-manager/SESSIONS.ser (Permission denied) any idea?

Answer (score 47):

Go to Tomcat bin directory and run the below command:

```
chmod +x *.sh
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Success with Apache Tomcat 8.5.16 on macOS 10.12.6

Comment: Success with Tomcat 10.0.10 on macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 for Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to the tomcat directory, which preferably should be "/usr/local/folder-name"

2) Check for the permissions for the folder: ls -l

3) Change the permissions using: sudo chmod -R 755 folder-name

4) Change the owner to the current owner: sudo chown -R owner-name:group-name folder-name
e.g sudo chown -R userName:admin folder-name

Try executing the script again and it should work.

Comment: From reading pages on [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11544/56752) and on [SuperUser Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/q/122420/212610), it seems something like Tomcat belongs in `/opt` rather than `/usr/local`: Not directly OS-related, from an independent vendor. And `/etc/opt/package` for configuration files, `/var/opt/package` for logs, spool and similar.