# When sudo chmod 755 /Library/Tomcat9/bin/*.sh occurred an error

Tags: java, tomcat

This is my Tomcat, I copied it under the `~/Library` directory:

[image]

When I modify the permission directory use:

```
sudo chmod 755 /Library/Tomcat9/bin/*.sh
```

Occurs an issue:

> chmod: /Library/Tomcat9/bin/*.sh: No such file or directory

The screenshot of issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod 755 /Library/{filename}` tries to change the permission of `filename` in the `Library` inside the root directory `/`. In your case there's no folder `Library` in the root directory, which is why you get the error `No such file or directory`.

I'd do it like this:

```
cd ~/Library/Tomcat9/bin     #change to the Library directory in your Home-Folder and further to Tomcat9/bin
sudo chmod 755 startup.sh    #inside /bin change the permission of the startup script
./startup.sh                 #execute the file
```

Comment: when I run `./startup.sh`, there comes the errors: `Cannot find ./catalina.sh
The file is absent or does not have execute permission
This file is needed to run this program`

Comment: @aircraft: This has been discussed already here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662710/tomcat-startup-script-permission-on-mac-os-x